Creating Lightning Web Runtime project does not initialize because of missing template
I am trying to spin up an LWR project based on npm init lwr@latest
I get the following error..
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '~/.npm/_npx/7a0e498e0957cb52/node_modules/create-lwr/template-markdown-static-site'
It seems the lwr distribution build only includes the /build folder, and missing the dependent files. Please see screenshot.
Also, the linked git repo in the npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/lwr?activeTab=readme
requires authentication https://github.com/salesforce-experience-platform-emu/lwr
, so I am not able to verify if the needed template is in place or not.
ls ~/.npm/_npx/7a0e498e0957cb52/node_modules/create-lwr/
build  LICENSE  package.json  README.md


Same here. It's clearly not even a "Developer Preview Feature". (Did you want to include a screenshot?) Maybe ask in the (not very lively) LWR group?

They messed up something in the latest template. Earlier versions work, later versions do not. This works for us on Ubuntu: npx create-lwr@0.14.5

Thanks for the tips and workarounds

Though it takes me further, create-lwr@0.14.5 is dodgy..
[error] ServerError: An unexpected error occurred: "Invalid LWC configuration in "/home/garricle/local/keysight-front-end/frontend-core-components/lwr-KT-lwc-components". Invalid npm module record "{"npm":"@lwrjs/client-modules"}", "@lwrjs/client-modules" npm module can't be resolved"
missing these ...
"@lwc/engine-dom": "^8.12.1",
"@lwc/synthetic-shadow": "^8.12.1",
"@lwrjs/client-modules": "^0.16.1",
"@lwrjs/loader": "^0.16.1",
"@lwrjs/o11y": "^0.16.1",
"@lwrjs/router": "^0.16.1"
